# pandas: getting the name of the column corresponding to the highest value in the row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF as follows:
[image]

What I want to get is a 1 Column df that contains the name of the column of the maximum value of the row, or the order number of that column. (see red circles in the pic)

Any suggestion?

here the data for copy and paste:

```
matrix = np.array([[0.92234683, 0.94209485, 0.90884652, 0.99763808],
       [0.86166401, 0.96755855, 0.9243107 , 0.94240756],
       [0.85457367, 0.9169915 , 0.95042024, 0.90661279],
       [0.83972504, 0.93902909, 0.91985442, 0.93765059],
       [0.84373323, 0.87762977, 0.91005636, 0.88525626]])
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['Y_clm1', 'Y_clm2', 'Y_clm3', 'Y_clm4'])
```

```
>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
0    Y_clm4
1    Y_clm2
2    Y_clm3
3    Y_clm2
4    Y_clm3
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

use `max`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
max(df) == 3
```

`max(df)` corresponds to `Y_clm4`